# Use XhrIo to populate Object's variables

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I'm trying to put a list of dictionary words from an AJAX call into a Dictionary object I've defined in JavaScript. I'm using Google Closure Toolkit to make the call as follows:

```
frankenstein.app.Dictionary = function(dictionaryUrl) {
  /** @private */ this._words = new goog.structs.Set();
  log("sending request");
  goog.net.XhrIo.send(dictionaryUrl, this.initDictionary);
}

frankenstein.app.Dictionary.prototype.initDictionary = function(e) {
    var xhr = e.target;
    this._words.addAll(xhr.getResponseText().split('\n'));
    log('Received dictionary file with ' + this._words.size());
}
```

Inside of the initDictionary method, unfortunately, "this" refers to the goog.net.XhrIo and not to the Dictionary object. Is there a way that I can get the Dictionary object referenced as the this in initDictionary? Or some other way to set the variables on it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback `frankenstein.app.Dictionary.prototype.initDictionary` could be bound to instances of `frankenstein.app.Dictionary` as follows:

```js
/** @constructor */
frankenstein.app.Dictionary = function(dictionaryUrl) {
  /** @private */ this._words = new goog.structs.Set();
  log("sending request");

  var xhr = new goog.net.XhrIo();
  goog.events.listenOnce(xhr, goog.net.EventType.COMPLETE, this.initDictionary,
      false /* capture phase */, this);
  xhr.send(dictionaryUrl);
};

frankenstein.app.Dictionary.prototype.initDictionary = function(e) {
  var xhr = /** @type {goog.net.XhrIo} */ (e.target);
  this._words.addAll(xhr.getResponseText().split('\n'));
  log('Received dictionary file with ' + this._words.size());
  xhr.dispose(); // Dispose of the XHR if it is not going to be reused.
};
```

The fifth argument to `goog.events.listenOnce` (or alternatively, `goog.events.listen`) is an optional object in whose scope the listener will be called.

Comment: I think I have a lot more to learn about Google Closure Tools! This helped a lot, thanks!